# Setting focus on a Blazor element

Tags: blazor

I'm using the server version of Blazor and in the follow example I have this error:

"JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being statically rendererd. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method."

```
File .razor:
      <RadzenTabs SelectedIndex="0" Change=@(args => OnChangeRadzenTab(args))>

File.cs:
        async void OnChangeRadzenTab(int value)
        {
            switch (value)
            {
               case 0:
                   await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("eval", $@"document.getElementById(""NameOfField"").focus()");
                   break;
```

But in the follow one, instead, the code run. Why there are these differences of behavour?

```
File .razor:
        <RadzenMask Mask="**/**/****" Pattern="[^0-9]" Name="EndDate" Id="EndDate"
                    @bind-Value=@EndDate  @onfocusout=@(args => OnFocusOutEndDate(args)) /> 

File.cs:
        async void OnFocusOutEndDate(FocusEventArgs? value)
        {
            if (!LibB.CheckDate(EndDate))
            {
                await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("eval", $@"document.getElementById(""EndDate"").focus()");
                Error = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you've put the first in an `@if` or `@foreach` block, and the second is not in a conditional block.  Either that, or the first Radzen control is creating sub-controls in that way, and they are calling the EventCallback during rendering.

Anyway, my solution for this problem is to conform to the error message and defer the JavaScript:

```
bool NeedFocusChange;
async Task OnFocusOutEndDate(FocusEventArgs? value) 
{
    if (!LibB.CheckDate(EndDate))
        NeedFocusChange = true;
} 
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (NeedFocusChange)
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("eval", $@"document.getElementById(""EndDate"").focus()");
        Error = true;
        NeedFocusChange = false;
     }
}
```

I don't know the RadzenControls, but if you can get an @ref to the "EndDate" component, you can use the new (.net 5) `FocusAsync` but it still uses JavaScript under the hood I think:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLypM7oBwyA